# How to get Cartodb.js to use https?

Tags: carto, sql, chart

I have a simple SQL query from my Cartodb account to populate a chart.

[Here is the link](http://njander.github.io/chartjs2/)

The chart works fine outside my company on a public network but I keep getting the following error when accessing it from inside my organization's network:

[image: this is the console error]

I think that I need to tell cartodb.js to use https when calling for the data. Can someone explain how I can do that?

Answer (score 4):

I wasn't able to get your page to load using Chrome without using the load unsafe script option because the script link is not using https, you could try changing:

```
<script src="http://libs.cartocdn.com/cartodb.js/v3/cartodb.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script src="https://cartodb-libs.global.ssl.fastly.net/cartodb.js/v3/3.15/cartodb.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is indeed the official recommendation from carto - https://github.com/CartoDB/cartodb.js/